# Google search on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

Whenever I am searching anything on Chrome i.e. directly typing in address bar and performing search. I am getting the result in which the first link is not available, only its content is available.

Images attached.

[image: Search result on Chrome]

Comment: err.. what's behind that white patch? In anycase looks like some extension is behind this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have an extension such as AdBlock Plus installed which is preventing the first Google search result from being displayed.  Try disabling this extension and re-entering your search.

How to disable a Google Chrome extension:

1. In your address bar, type `chrome://extensions/`
2. Find the extension that may be behind this problem.
3. Uncheck the "Enabled" box next to the extension name.
4. Restart Chrome.

For a more detailed answer, post a list of your installed extensions and I shall tell you which ones to disable.  Also, I **can** confirm that your issue is not related to searching in the Omnibar, as the below screenshot shows.[image: The issue is not Omnibar-related.]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the "SelectionLinks" extension installed: [that's a malware](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-selectionlinks-ads/).

Go to `chrome://extensions` and remove it. If you can't remove it from there, check out the link above or google (using Incognito Mode, that should put KO the offending extension) for removal instructions specific for your OS.